# Roslyn - namespaces

Tags: c#, roslyn

Can anyone tell what namespace the `Syntax` class is in?
I have installed all the roslyn packages through nuget but I don't know what namespace the static factory methods for creating expression syntax objects is in.

Also a lot of the examples of Roslyn on the web are using these namespaces

```
using Roslyn.Compilers;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;
```

Are these obsolete now? I am using the following

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
```

Can somebody explain the difference?

Comment: `Roslyn.*` is from the 2012 preview.

Comment: We used the Roslyn namespaces until we had figured out a proper name for what to call it. The Microsoft.CodeAnalysis names are the final ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can gather the namespaces are obsolete now.
`SyntaxFactory` replaces `Syntax` if anyone is interested.